# Cannot expand height of TableView cell in TableView Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I created a table view controller which is a parent of table view cell inside it:

[image]

I have set the default row height of the cell to be 375:

[image]

And inside it is a UIImageView which also has a height constraint of 374.

But when I run the app, the height allocated to each row is very less and does not seem to change:

[image]

How can I change the change the height to my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the properties of your Table View also you need to mention cell height, check screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. This totally worked! What is this Section Height?

Answer (score 0):

try to implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`
and don't forget to add `[cell layoutIfNeeded]` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.